# How to give the Schema access to the specific IP Address in oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I needed to give access to specific IP address to access the schema in the oracle database.

Can any one help me how can i achive it.

Using Pl/SQl or some other if.

Answer (score 0):

Access can only be granted to users and roles, not an IP Address.

You *could* fake it by creating an account with access and then creating a [LOGON trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm#CIHEFABC) to restrict access, although I recommend not doing it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_user
  AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
  BEGIN
    if sys_context('userenv', 'ip_address') <> '175.45.177.50' then
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'This IP cannot access this database.');
    end if;
 END;
/
```

This might be a bad idea for several reasons.  IP addresses can be faked and are not a good way of authenticating users.  Also, be careful with this because these triggers can block a lot of users.  (Warning: I did not test the above code as I don't have a database I can destroy right now.)  Also, these triggers don't block users with the DBA role so it can be tricky to test them.